# Memory read error when calling DLL functions

Tags: c++, dll

I have two projects: app.exe and engine.dll (with implicitly lib linked in Visual Studio 2017). When I try to call this basic code in app.exe from engine.dll I get memory read error (Access Violation). Here's short example:

```
// In DLL .h
class Engine // pure virtual class
{
public:
    Engine() { }

/* pure virtual functions here ...*/

    static Engine* Create(DefaultAllocator& Allocator);
};

// In DLL CPP
Engine* Engine::Create(DefaultAllocator& Allocator)
{
    EngineImpl* impl = NEW_OBJ(Allocator, EngineImpl)(Allocator); // NEW_OBJ is a simple place holder
    // changing to 'new' didn't help too

    return impl;
}

void Engine::InitSomething()
{
// ERROR: Allocating anything here will be corrupted 
}

// In another DLL CPP
struct NewPlaceholder {};
#define NEW_OBJ(allocator, ...) new (NewPlaceholder(), (allocator).allocate(sizeof(__VA_ARGS__))) __VA_ARGS__

// Main.cpp from EXE
int main(int32 Argc, char* Argv[])
{
    static DefaultAllocator Allocator; // Has Allocate/Deallocate methods (malloc/free)

    Engine* engine = Engine::Create(Allocator); 
// And now as I call any function from Engine I get corrupted results
    engine->InitSomething();
}
```

Both projects are /MDd with exactly same settings. App.exe has Engine in references.

Comment: Single step in the debugger and look at all pointers in the stack/watch window

Comment: It shows correct call stack trace, but values are corrupted when it reaches the engine.dll code